# How to style a rectangular div with elliptical rounded sides?

Tags: css

How to style a rectangular div with elliptical rounded sides?

[image: Rectangle with elliptical rounded sides]

Comment: I need a div of this shape for a slider.

Answer (score 2):

You can get an ellipse by setting border-radius 50%.

You can get two elements, one inside the other, with different sizes, and so get the 2 ellipses needed

```
.test {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden; 
}


.test:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -30%;
    top: 10%;
    width: 160%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-radius: 50%;

}
```

In this case, using an pseudo element , and so, only one div is needed

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/btjbD/)

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked out [this website?](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp) Try this:

```
div
{
border:2px solid;
border-radius:25px;
}
```

Comment: I have tried border-radius but It just makes only 2 opposite sides elliptical at a time.